# Android : Duplicate files copied in APK org/apache/xml/security/resource/schema/xmldsig-core-schema.rng

Tags: android, android-studio

I am getting the error when building apk for my project

```
 com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.builder.packaging.DuplicateFileException: Duplicate files copied in APK org/apache/xml/security/resource/schema/xmldsig-core-schema.rng
```

I am not able to trace this to any thing. This started happening suddenly. How do I go about debuging this?

Comment: add gradle file ,maybe use 2 version of one library in project

Comment: show your `build.gradle`

Comment: there are 5 modules there. Do you want all the 5 gradles?

Comment: show dependencies in 5 build.gradle

Answer (score 1):

Change your app build.gradle:

```
android {
    ...
    packagingOptions {
        pickFirst 'org/apache/xml/security/resource/**' // add this
    }
}
```